# validation class that serve many classes but as build conflict

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, design-patterns, software-design

i have solution of many projects (.NET), with project dependencies.

i need to create validation class that serve many classes, this class shall be at the end of the dependency order, to be able to "know" many types, but shall be invoke be some projects above his dependency order.

what is the software architecture can support\overcome this conflict?

Comment: " this class shall be at the end of the dependency order,...  to be able to "know" many types" I am confused. In my understanding if your at the end of the order then you don't depend on anyone, but everybody on you. So how can you know any type above you?

Comment: maybe an extra project with an independent Interface implemented by the classes you want to validate? You might be more explicite at describing your goal.

Comment: What specifically do you intend the "validation class" to do, how is it used? Is it just a collection of utility methods (`isNameValid`, `isPositiveInteger`, etc)?  Or something with more domain knowledge?